# Оставить только фамилии и подставить их в теги

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть фамилии и инициалы авторов:

```
authors = ['Пупкин М.И.', 'Скутина О.Л.']
```

Пытаюсь оставить только фамилии обоих авторов:

```
def get_ln(authors):
    for i in authors:
        a = i.split()[0]
    return '<SUBFIELD.A>' + str(a) + '</SUBFIELD.A>'

get_ln = get_ln(authors)

print(get_ln)
```

Но получается только фамилия второго автора. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подставить в теги обе фамилии? Желаемый результат:

```
<SUBFIELD.A>Пупкин</SUBFIELD.A>
<SUBFIELD.A>Скутина</SUBFIELD.A>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращается фамилия последнего автора, потому что в конце цикла в `a` хранится только она, т.к. каждую итерацию переменная `а` перезаписывается. Нужно в цикле сохранять фамилии в другой список, например.

Возвращает список, элементами которого являются нужные строки:

```
def get_ln(authors):
    names = [] # пустой список, куда будем складывать фамилии
    for i in authors:
        a = i.split()[0]
        # добавляем полученную фамилию в список вместе с тэгами
        names.append('<SUBFIELD.A>' + a + '</SUBFIELD.A>')
    return names
```

Результат:

```
['<SUBFIELD.A>Пупкин</SUBFIELD.A>', '<SUBFIELD.A>Скутина</SUBFIELD.A>']
```

---

PS. Обратите внимание на эту строчку:

```
get_ln = get_ln(authors)
```

Ни в коем случае, **НИКОГДА!**, не делайте так. После этой строчки нельзя будет использовать функцию `get_ln()`, потому что `get_ln` теперь не функция, а список фамилий. Не нужно давать переменным и функциям одинаковые имена.

Comment: огромное спасибо!!! Замечание обязательно учту!!!